# Por que o DELETE dá erro?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, laravel

Tenho a seguinte função em jquery que dá o delete no registro. Ele chega a deletar o registro mas não vai para o `success`, ele vai para o `error`. Por que será?

```
function deletar_cliente(id_cliente)
  {
    var mensagem_sucesso = "";
    var mensagem_erro = "";
    var url_cliente = "cadastro_clientes.php";
    $.ajax({
      url: url_base + "clientes/" + id_cliente,
      type: 'DELETE',
      dataType: 'json',
    }).success(function(data)
    {
      console.log(data);
    }).error(function(data)
    {
      console.log('erro');
    });
  }
```

CLIENTES CONTROLLER:

```
public function destroy($id)
{

    $clientes = Clientes::find($id);

    if(!$clientes) {
      return response()->json([
        'message'   => 'Cliente não encontrado',
      ], 404);
    }

    $clientes->delete();
}
```

ROUTES:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

Route::get('/', function () {
  return response()->json(['message' => 'Rep Api', 'status' => 'Connected']);;
});

Route::resource('clientes', 'ClientesController');
Route::resource('fornecedores', 'FornecedoresController');
Route::resource('usuarios', 'UsuariosController');
Route::resource('estados', 'EstadosController');
Route::resource('municipios', 'MunicipiosController');
Route::post('autenticacao', 'AuthController@authenticate');
Route::get('get-municipios/{estados_id}', 'MunicipiosController@getMunicipios');
```

Comment: `cadastro_clientes.php` retorna o que um json? como ele é? tentou dar um `console.log(data)` em `.error()`?

Comment: Simplesmente não me retorna nada. Ele já cai direto para o error.

Comment: Ele chega a deletar, pois vejo no DB ele deleta. E no error ele dá: {readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: ƒ, getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ, setRequestHeader: ƒ, overrideMimeType: ƒ, …}
abort
:
ƒ (a)
always
:
ƒ ()
complete
:
ƒ ()
done
:
ƒ ()
error
:
ƒ ()
fail
:
ƒ ()
getAllResponseHeaders
:
ƒ ()
getResponseHeader
:
ƒ (a)
overrideMimeType
:
ƒ (a)
pipe
:
ƒ ()
progress
:
ƒ ()
promise
:
ƒ (a)
readyState
:
4
responseText
:
""
setRequestHeader
:
ƒ (a,b)
state

Comment: No `cadastro_clientes.php` deixe como ultima linha `echo json_encode(array('teste'=> 'teste...'));` e coloca `console.log(data)` no `error()`

Comment: Será que não é alguma configuração do laravel? Pois estou usando esta api RestFull do laravel php

Comment: Qual versão do jQuery está usando?

Comment: Ao invés de model::find(id) tenta com $cliente =model::findOrFail(id) e na sequência dá um dd($cliente); e trata o  retorno

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No seu controller, força ele retornar uma mensagem de sucesso:

```
public function destroy($id){

$clientes = Clientes::find($id);

   if(!$clientes) {
     return response()->json([
       'message'   => 'Cliente não encontrado',
     ], 404);
   }

   $clientes->delete();
}
```

Vi no [tutorial](https://rafaell-lycan.com/2016/construindo-restful-api-laravel-parte-3/) o autor forçando um 204:

```
return response()->json($clientes->delete(), 204);
```

Outra tentativa que você pode usar:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: "json",
    cache: false,
    url: url_base + "clientes/" + id_cliente,
    success: function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    },
    error: function (response) {
        alert('Error - ' + response.responseText);
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```

Por mais que não resolva posta nos comentários os erro que vai retornar no console ou alert.